# JUnit 5 -- reuse a nested test class with different state?

Tags: junit, junit5

Student here.  In JUnit 5, what is the best way to invoke a [@Nested](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested) test class multiple times, but with slightly different state each time?

I see that JUnit 5 has an (experimental) [@ParameterizedTest](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) feature that is based on the (non-experimental) [@TestTemplate](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-templates) feature, but both of those apply to test methods only, rather than nested test classes.

I have a heavy `@Nested` test class that needs to be invoked once for each value of an enum (preferably with a distinct `@Tag` value for each invocation), and I would prefer to avoid the "copy-and-paste" method of parameterization.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to execute a test class multiple times in JUnit Jupiter.

To participate in the discussion, see the following issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/878